# Como utilizar o push pull do bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho um template com a estrutura ilustrada pela imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando na documentação vi que combinando as classes `col-*-push-*` e `col-*-pull-*` é possível   produzir esse efeito

Tentei e pesquisei bastante sem sucesso. Preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 pull-md-9">Teste</div>
  <div class="col-md-9 push-md-3">Exemplo</div>
</div>
```